# What would be the real life equivalent of the drugs and syringes that make people pass out in movies and shows?

Tags: fiction, combat, crime

Not sure if this is the right place to ask.

**Problem:** I'm writing a book with a scene where these two criminals are trying to kidnap someone, and the victim is fighting back. Criminal A is fighting them, criminal B has a syringe with some sort of fluid that makes you go unconscious when injected.

**Question:** what would this fluid be? There's scenes in a lot of movies where a guy sticks a syringe in someone's neck and they pass out almost immediately. Similarly, someone's drink gets drugged and they pass out later. I'm not planning on kidnapping anyone, I'm just curious as to what the actual substances/chemicals/drugs would be in reality.

Comment: Do the criminals care any about the safety of their victim? Because getting the dose wrong can be deadly (and so can using the wrong drug on the wrong person). -- [This page](https://rk.md/2015/drugs-used-general-anesthesia/) lists a few drugs used by an anesthesiologist. Whether those would be good (and safe) options for criminals, I don't know.

Comment: Why not just a chloroform rag? A syringe is a little too much. If you want a syringe, it wouldn't take alot for it to work and too much would probably kill them.

Comment: In bad movies people fall over dead instantly after being stabbed in the stomach, it's called **DEUS EX MACHINA** or *because the plot needed it*.... For real life, Ask Bill Cosby? This question is not about writing, it's about real life criminal behavior that imitates bad writing. Voting to close because it's lacks research and is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

There are some obvious and well-known ones. Chloroform and rohypnol come to mind. You could look up "anesthetics" on the Internet and probably find others. I'm not a doctor so if I was writing a story where the criminal gave someone a knock-out drug, I'd probably just call it "a knock-out drug". Otherwise you're setting yourself up for a reader with some knowledge of medicine to say, "What!? That not how fubarstatin works!"

Indeed I recall reading once that all the stories where someone soaks a rag in chloroform and uses it to knock out his kidnap victim are bogus, because chloroform won't really knock someone out that fast. I have no idea if that's true or not, which is why I'd stay away from it.

BTW, reminds me ... My 20-something daughter once said that the best pick-up line a guy ever tried to use on her was, "Excuse me, miss. Does this rag smell like chloroform to you?" :-)